# Induction functor reflects isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, tensor-products

Let $k$ be a field and $R$ a commutative associative unital $k$-algebra with augmentation $\epsilon:R\rightarrow k$. Assume that $R$ is either a local Artinian ring or a complete local ring (i.e. it is $\mathfrak{m}$-adically complete, for $\mathfrak{m}$ the unique maximal ideal of $R$).

Consider the induction aka extension of scalars functor with respect to the augmentation $\epsilon$

$$\operatorname{Ind}_R^k: R\mathsf{-mod}\rightarrow k\mathsf{-mod}$$

given by $\operatorname{\operatorname{Ind}}_R^k(B)=k\otimes_RB$. Here we consider $k$ as a right $R$-module by restriction of scalars along $\epsilon$. The abelian group $k\otimes_RB$ becomes a left $k$-module via the left multiplication of $k$. Restrict the functor $\operatorname{Ind}_R^k$ to the full subcategory of $R\mathsf{-mod}$ given by the free $R$-modules. Call this restricted functor $F$.

I am trying to show that $F$ reflects isomorphisms. Is this even true?

Comment: Is $ R$ commutative?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Yes! Sorry for not writing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof when $R$ is commutative and local: The restriction to free modules is important. It lets us work with matrices. The problem then becomes: if a matrix over $R$ becomes invertible over $k$, then it is already invertible over $R$. But this is clear using the determinant and since the invertible elements of $R$ are exactly the ones that become invertible in $k$.

Comment: I fix the formulas later. I am on my phone now.

Comment: Determinant arguments are not valid over noncommutative local rings, I believe.

Comment: Oh I thought R is assumed to be commutative... I add this. But the matrix interpretation works in any case.